# Irregular shape buttons on the UI of Android app

Tags: android, layout

I am in the process of creating an app which requires irregular shaped buttons. I know that i can use image buttons and have the irregular shapes set as the images but no matter what is the shape of the image, it always occupies a rectangular area on the screen.
Is it possible to have the button occupy the exact shape of the image alone?
Do i need to create a custom control or layout for doing this or is there any other valid approach?
If i need to create a custom layout then how do i ensure that the space enclosed by all the buttons that i have placed on the layout is always circular or elliptic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start custom and try to generalize enough to allow others to use and participate in the development of your: 'anyshape' android ui component(s).

The J2ME platform's ui components took that route some years ago.

In any case, as you might allready know:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html